# how to use sql.trans in two methods?

Tags: c#, .net, sql, oracle

i have cut and paste buttons while cutting i have one sql operation and while pasting one sql operation . how to use transation statement for this .

```
protected void btnCut_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        hidCutnode.Value = TreeView2.SelectedNode.Value;
        string sqlQuery = "update CUSTOMIZEDTREE set parentid='" + 0 + "' where nodeid='" + hidCutnode.Value + "'";
        string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.69.200.62)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)));User Id=apex_demo;Password=apex_demo;";
        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
        con.Open();
        tran = con.BeginTransaction();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, con);
        cmd.Transaction = tran;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
}

protected void btnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        hidPastenode.Value = TreeView2.SelectedNode.Value;
        try
        {
            string sqlQuery = "update CUSTOMIZEDTREE set parentid='" + hidPastenode.Value + "' where nodeid='" + hidCutnode.Value + "'";
            string connectionString = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=10.69.200.62)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=orcl)));User Id=apex_demo;Password=apex_demo;";
            OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(connectionString);
            con.Open();
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(sqlQuery, con);
            tran = con.BeginTransaction();
           // cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.Transaction = tran;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            tran.Commit();

            con.Close();
            PopulateCustomTree();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            tran.Rollback();
            ex.ToString();
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass `transaction` object as function parameter to the second method and dont `commit` in method1. Use `BeginTransaction` in first method only.

Comment: its inbuild method . how to pass it?

Comment: What do you mean by inbuilt method? You meant to say you can't modify the code?

Comment: protected void btnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)

Comment: its buttons inbuild click event . how to change the parameter?

Comment: You can make you two methods, lets say Cut and Paste, call cut method from btnCut_Click and paste method from other button event handler.

Comment: protected void btnPaste_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Paste(tran);
        }

Comment: i used like this . but its null(tran). because of post back i think?

Comment: Are you on Asp.Net? Then hold the transaction in session

Comment: ok.. i used that. one more question connection should close in second method rit?

Comment: its not a good practice to store the transaction in session. you can execute both statements in your paste method.

Answer (score 0):

```
SqlTransaction trn = connect.BeginTransaction();
            try
            {

                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query);
                command.Transaction = trn;
                command.Connection = connect;
                connect.Open();
                command.CommandTimeout = 0;
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                trn.Commit();
                

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                trn.Rollback();
            }
            connect.Close();
```